# what is the diff Scanner and BufferedReader

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

What is the difference between reading a file by `System` and `BufferedReader`?

```html
 File fileName = new File("E:/go.txt");
  Scanner obj = new Scanner(fileName);
  int largest = 0;

  while (obj.hasNextInt()) {
   int input = obj.nextInt();
   if (largest < input) {

    largest = input;
   }
   
  }
  System.out.println("largest no. is:" + largest);
```

Comment: Use Scanner if you want to "parse" a file, it provides lot of functions to read input selectively. Use BufferedReader + FileReader to read all contents of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though both are meant for standard input but `Scanner` is used for parsing tokens from the contents of the stream while `BufferedReader` just reads the stream and does not do any special parsing.

- `BufferedReader` is `synchronized` and `Scanner` is not, so its up to you to decide.Use `BufferedReader` if you're working with multiple threads.
- The `Scanner` has a little buffer (1KB char buffer) as opposed to the BufferedReader (8KB byte buffer), but it's more than enough.
- `BufferedReader` is a bit fast as compared to scanner.
- Scanner hides `IOException` while `BufferedReader` throws it immediately

Comment: what type of synchronization is done in bufferedReader?

Comment: **BufferedReader is synchronized, so read operations on a BufferedReader can safely be done from multiple threads**